# How to implement multithreading in Libsoup server?

Tags: c, multithreading, glib, gnome

I want to implement multithreading in Libsoup server such that every time when a client request comes, a new thread will be created to serve that request.
How can I implement this using the Libsoup and GLib libraries?

My current server main code is like this:

```
sending_file =  fopen("abc/project_foo.zip", "r");
fseek(sending_file, 0L, SEEK_END);
size_of_file = ftell(sending_file);
fseek(sending_file, 0L, SEEK_SET);
int port = 15000;

server = soup_server_new(SOUP_SERVER_RAW_PATHS,TRUE,SOUP_SERVER_PORT,port, SOUP_SERVER_SERVER_HEADER,"simple-httpd",NULL);


soup_server_add_handler(server , "/foo" , server_callback, NULL , NULL);
soup_server_run_async (server);

printf("Waiting for Requests...\n");

//Running a main loop so Async will work
GMainLoop *loop;
loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, TRUE);
g_main_loop_run (loop);
return 0;
```

Comment: Please share any approaches you have tried so far.

Comment: I have added my main function code

Answer (score 1):

Create a new thread in the callback you pass to `soup_server_add_handler`.  The [manual explains the rest](https://developer.gnome.org/libsoup/stable/libsoup-server-howto.html#id-1.2.6.7); the relevant part:

> By default, libsoup assumes that you have completely finished processing the message when you return from the callback, and that it can therefore begin sending the response. If you are not ready to send a response immediately (eg, you have to contact another server, or wait for data from a database), you must call `soup_server_pause_message` on the message before returning from the callback. This will delay sending a response until you call `soup_server_unpause_message`. (You must also connect to the `finished` signal on the message in this case, so that you can break off processing if the client unexpectedly disconnects before you start sending the data.)

So make sure you call `soup_server_pause_message` in the callback you pass to `soup_server_add_handler`, then when you're done processing the request in your thread call `soup_server_unpause_message`.

Instead of creating a new thread for each request you might want to think about using a [thread pool](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Thread-Pools.html), but the idea is pretty much the same—just add a task to the pool instead of creating a new thread.